# amp pages stopped working at nextjs project, error at cdn.ampproject.org, resources cannot be loaded

Tags: reactjs, amp-html, next.js

I have an issue with AMP CDN. It has been integrated into Nextjs as I use the AMP feature in Nextjs itself, it was working fine yesterday but today the following error came up:

[image: image of the error in console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This crash occurs when Next.js cannot load `cdn.ampproject.org`. For solving this problem first Check the network connection then you must necessarily `restart the next.js` server or dev server.

```
npm run dev
```

or

```
npm run start
```

Comment: Thank you, I have discovered the cause of the prob is the INTERNET CONNECTION, as somehow cdn.ampproject.org doesn't load on my ordinary connection, so I had to use VPN to be able to access it and the error no more shows